# R: quantmod - getSymbols to argument

Tags: r, download, symbols, quantmod

I am using `getSymbols` in library [quantmod](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf) in R to load SP500 data. When I set the `to` argument to "2021-01-28", the data is only downloaded up to and including "2021-01-27" while the help function for [getSymbols.yahoo](https://rdrr.io/cran/quantmod/man/getSymbols.yahoo.html) says that data is retrieved through this date. According to this, shouldn't the data be downloaded until the end of "2021-01-28"?

```
> library(quantmod)
> SP500=getSymbols("^GSPC", src="yahoo",auto.assign=FALSE,to="2021-01-28")
> tail(SP500)
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2021-01-20   3816.22   3859.75  3816.22    3851.85  4551790000       3851.85
2021-01-21   3857.46   3861.45  3845.05    3853.07  4484460000       3853.07
2021-01-22   3844.24   3852.31  3830.41    3841.47  5080430000       3841.47
2021-01-25   3851.68   3859.23  3797.16    3855.36  6955860000       3855.36
2021-01-26   3862.96   3870.90  3847.78    3849.62  6029090000       3849.62
2021-01-27   3836.83   3836.83  3732.48    3750.77  9878040000       3750.77
```

Answer (score 1):

It should, but it doesn't. It is an issue with yahoo and also depends from which exchange the data is coming from. See [github issue 258](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/258) for more information.